# How can I get this into a dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a list I got from an API:

```
[[{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Line, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities',
   'id': 'piccadilly',
   'name': 'Piccadilly',
   'modeName': 'tube',
   'disruptions': [],
   'created': '2019-08-20T16:25:25.35Z',
   'modified': '2019-08-20T16:25:25.35Z',
   'lineStatuses': [],
   'routeSections': [],
   'serviceTypes': [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineServiceTypeInfo, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities',
     'name': 'Regular',
     'uri': '/Line/Route?ids=Piccadilly&serviceTypes=Regular'},
    {'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineServiceTypeInfo, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities',
     'name': 'Night',
     'uri': '/Line/Route?ids=Piccadilly&serviceTypes=Night'}],
   'crowding': {'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Crowding, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities'}}],
 [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Line, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities',
   'id': 'victoria',
   'name': 'Victoria',
   'modeName': 'tube',
   'disruptions': [],
   'created': '2019-08-20T16:25:25.36Z',
   'modified': '2019-08-20T16:25:25.36Z',
   'lineStatuses': [],
   'routeSections': [],
   'serviceTypes': [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineServiceTypeInfo, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities',
     'name': 'Regular',
     'uri': '/Line/Route?ids=Victoria&serviceTypes=Regular'},
    {'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineServiceTypeInfo, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities',
     'name': 'Night',
     'uri': '/Line/Route?ids=Victoria&serviceTypes=Night'}]
```

I want to get a dataframe with these columns: id, name, modeName, disruptions, serviceTypes, etc but I cant find a correct solution.

This is what I tried:

```
dflines = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["id", "name", "modeName", "disruptions", "serviceTypes"])

for i, row in range(len(info)):
    id = row["id"]
    name = row["name"]
    modeName = row["modeName"]
    disruptions = row["disruptions"]
    dflines.loc[i] = [id, name, modeName, disruptions, want, serviceTypes]

dflines.head(20)
```

I got this error: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-bec7efd03786> in <module>
      1 dflines = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["id", "name", "modeName", "disruptions", "serviceTypes"])
      2 
----> 3 for i, row in range(len(info)):
      4     id = row["id"]
      5     name = row["name"]

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you getting any error or unexpected behavior?

Comment: Yes @Yash Krishan I got this error: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-bec7efd03786> in <module>
      1 dflines = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["id", "name", "modeName", "disruptions", "serviceTypes"])
      2 
----> 3 for i, row in range(len(info)):
      4     id = row["id"]
      5     name = row["name"]

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Comment: Put the error in your original question for better readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
info=[[{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Line, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities',
   'id': 'piccadilly',
   'name': 'Piccadilly',
   'modeName': 'tube',
   'disruptions': [],
   'created': '2019-08-20T16:25:25.35Z',
   'modified': '2019-08-20T16:25:25.35Z',
   'lineStatuses': [],
   'routeSections': [],
   'serviceTypes': [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineServiceTypeInfo, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities',
     'name': 'Regular',
     'uri': '/Line/Route?ids=Piccadilly&serviceTypes=Regular'},
    {'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineServiceTypeInfo, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities',
     'name': 'Night',
     'uri': '/Line/Route?ids=Piccadilly&serviceTypes=Night'}],
   'crowding': {'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Crowding, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities'}}],
 [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Line, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities',
   'id': 'victoria',
   'name': 'Victoria',
   'modeName': 'tube',
   'disruptions': [],
   'created': '2019-08-20T16:25:25.36Z',
   'modified': '2019-08-20T16:25:25.36Z',
   'lineStatuses': [],
   'routeSections': [],
   'serviceTypes': [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineServiceTypeInfo, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities',
     'name': 'Regular',
     'uri': '/Line/Route?ids=Victoria&serviceTypes=Regular'},
    {'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineServiceTypeInfo, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities',
     'name': 'Night',
     'uri': '/Line/Route?ids=Victoria&serviceTypes=Night'}]}]]
info = np.squeeze(info).tolist()
dflines = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["id", "name", "modeName", "disruptions", "serviceTypes"])
dfserviceTypes=pd.DataFrame(columns =["$type","name","uri"])
i=0
j=0
for dic in info:
    for key in dic:
        if key in dflines.columns.tolist():
            dflines.loc[i,key]=str(dic[key])

        if key=='serviceTypes':
            for dic2 in dic[key]:
                for key2 in dic2:
                    if key2 in dfserviceTypes.columns.tolist():
                         dfserviceTypes.loc[j,key2]=str(dic2[key2])
                j+=1
    i+=1
```

**keep in mind that visualization is easier if it divide into two dataframes so as not to have to face the task of inserting a dataframe into another so as not to lose information**

```
dflines
```

> Output:

```
id  name        modeName    disruptions serviceTypes
0   piccadilly  Piccadilly  tube    []  [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Line...
1   victoria    Victoria    tube    []  [{'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Line...
```

**and servicestypes:**

```
dfserviceTypes
```

> Output:

```
    $type                                               name     uri
0   Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineServiceTypeI...   Regular /Line/Route?ids=Piccadilly&serviceTypes=Regular
1   Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineServiceTypeI...   Night   /Line/Route?ids=Piccadilly&serviceTypes=Night
2   Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineServiceTypeI...   Regular /Line/Route?ids=Victoria&serviceTypes=Regular
3   Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineServiceTypeI...   Night   /Line/Route?ids=Victoria&serviceTypes=Night
```

Comment: Thank you @lostCode, please could you tell me how can I take the values from the columns serviceType and crowding? I tried but I cant get the right solution.

Comment: i upload a complete solution!

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is due to your attempt to 'unpack' two values from the `range` iterator

```
for i, row in range(len(info)):
```

The `range` function returns a iteration of a single value (i.e. `0, 1, 2, ...`). You probably want to `enumerate`, like this:

```
for i, row in enumerate(info):
```

The `enumerate` function returns the value of the iteration plus the index, like `(0, first_value), (1, second_value), ...`